# Проблема с абсолютным позиционированием блока

Tags: html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток.
Есть сайт - http://improveagnc.ru/
При наведении на любой продукт, появляется описание. Но это описание смещает нижестоящие блоки. Если задать блоку с описанием позишн абсолют, то он вылезает из box-shadow и затемняется вместе с остальными блоками вокруг.
Хочу сделать как здесь: https://i-store.net/
Вот что имеется на данный момент, подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать.

```css
.products>li.isotope-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.excerpt {
  display: none;
}

.isotope-item:hover .excerpt {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="isotope-item post-2531 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-apple product_cat-iphone product_cat-iphone-6s first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="opacity: 1;">

  <div class="shadow">
    <div class="image_frame scale-with-grid product-loop-thumb" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
      <div class="image_wrapper">
        <a href="http://improveagnc.ru/product/iphone-7/">
          <div class="mask"></div><img width="300" height="300" src="http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-300x300.jpg" class="scale-with-grid wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-180x180.jpg 180w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-146x146.jpg 146w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-50x50.jpg 50w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-75x75.jpg 75w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-85x85.jpg 85w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1-80x80.jpg 80w, http://improveagnc.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2820-1.jpg 600w"
            sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></a>
        <div class="image_links double"><a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=2531" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="2531" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart product_type_simple"><i class="icon-basket"></i></a>
          <a class="link" href="http://improveagnc.ru/product/iphone-7/"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div><a href="http://improveagnc.ru/product/iphone-7/"><span class="product-loading-icon added-cart"></span></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">

    <h4><a href="http://improveagnc.ru/product/iphone-7/">IPhone 7</a></h4>


    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">30,000.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span>
    </span>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <p>Защита от брызг и воды, новая камера 12Мп и фронтальная 7Мп, ярче дисплей, больше аккумулятор, новый процессор A10 Fusion, стереодинамики.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Делается это так !**

Высота overlay элемента *не важна* вообще .. ну собственно смотрите пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .1s linear;
  position: relative;
  z-index: ;
}

.block img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.block:hover .item {
  height: 450px;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
@media(max-width:900px){
 .wrapper{
   text-align:center;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://www.sojones.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/april_11_enyce-clothing_company_launching_womens-shoes_and_hoisery_collections_01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p> Футболка <b>Enyce</b></p>
      <span>цена: 3Р-р</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Футболка</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

дэмо с **мини** *мобильной версией* : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pazPwZ?editors=1100 ..... требуется доработка